# Convergence of $\sum (z - a_k)^{-1}$ on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{a_k\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $a_k$ be a sequence of complex numbers and $A = \{a_k\}$. Suppose that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{|a_k|}$$

converges.

I want to show that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z - a_k}$$

converges to an analytic function on $\mathbb{C} \setminus A$.

However, I am unsure how to do this.

I initially thought I could use the Weierstrass M-Test for this. If I can show that $(z - a_k)^{-1} < M_k$ where $\sum M_k < \infty$, then $\sum (z - a_k)^{-1}$ would converge uniformly on $\mathbb{C} \setminus A$ and it would in fact converge to an analytic function since each of the terms is analytic.

But I do not think this approach can be used (can it?) because for each $(z - a_k)^{-1}$, the term can become arbitrarily large as $z$ approaches $a_k$, so no constant $M_k$ can be a bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{|a_k|}$ implies that
$a_k \to \infty$. Therefore, for a fixed $R > 0$ there is a 
$N \in \Bbb N$ such that $|a_k| > 2R$ for $k > N$.

Now you can split
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z - a_k} = \sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{z - a_k}
+ \sum_{k=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{z - a_k} \, .
$$
The first sum is finite and clearly analytic on $\Bbb C \setminus A$.

The second part converges uniformly on $|z| < R$ because
$$
\biggl|\frac{1}{z - a_k}\biggr| \le \frac{1}{|a_k| - |z|}
\le \frac{1}{|a_k| - R} \le  \frac{1}{|a_k| - |a_k|/2}
=  \frac{2}{|a_k|}
$$
for $k > N$.